# Get part of the value from a select option drop down?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an HTML code built in Dreamweaver utilizing ASP
How can I get just the userID into a input text field and the userTitle into another input text field and the userName into another input text field of a table.  It return all three as combination text in the input field.  How to separate them.  HELP PLEASE!

Code:

```
<HTML>
<%
Response.Buffer
infoDoc = ""
if Session("userTitle") <> "" and Session("userID")<> "" Then
infoDoc = "<option value '" & rs("userID) & "'" & rs("userName") & "'" & selections & ">" & rs("userTitle") </option>

Else
Session("userName") = ""
Session("userID") = 1
Session("userTitle") = ""

End If
sql= Select * From Users Order by userTitle
set rs= Conn.Execute(sql) Then
selections = "selected"
End If
infoDoc = infoDoc & "<option value '" & rs("userID) & "'" & rs("userName") & "'" & selections & ">" & rs("userTitle") </option>
rs.movement
selections = ""
Loop
rs.close
set rs=Nothing
%>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Select User</td>
<td><Select id=select onchange="myFunction()" name=select><% infoDoc %></Select></td>
<tr>ID
<td><input name=ID type=text id=ID disabled></td>
</tr>
<tr>Name
<td><input name=name type=text id=name disabled></td>
</tr>
<tr>ID
<td><input name=title type=text id=title disabled></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementByID("ID") = document.getElementByID("select").value
}
</script>
</HTML>
```

Comment: do you want to get selected text everytime selection changed and separate them to three value (userID, userTitle, userName) and fill to 3 input elements? Can you show more code of `myFunction()`

Comment: everytime the selection changes the values in the input elements will update.

Comment: var e = document.getElementById("select");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;                                                   document.getElementByID("ID") = strUser;                                                     which return 1 james director

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction(thizz) {
    var str = thizz.options[thizz.selectedIndex].text.split("your_separated_char");
    if(str.length == 3) {
        document.getElementById("ID").value = str[0];
        document.getElementById("Name").value = str[1];
        document.getElementById("title").value = str[2];
    }
}
```

`your_separated_char` can be a whitespace, comma, dot, etc...

Change to pass `this` param is the select element to the func like this:

```
<td><Select id=select onchange="myFunction(this)" name=select><% infoDoc %></Select></td>
```